# C# and Azure CosmosDB REST API: how to execute stored procedure using HTTPClient.PostAsync?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure using Azure CosmosDB REST API. According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/execute-a-stored-procedure#example) I need to pass an "array" containing stored proc input parameters.

In my case, I need to pass one parameter and it's an object. I have the object serialized but I can't figure out how to pass it as HTTPContent into PostAsync method. What exact type of HTTPContent I should use and what type I should convert my object to in order to create HTTPContent?

When I execute this SP using Postman, my request body looks like this:

```
["{\r\n\"id\" : \"someid\",\r\n\"data\": \"somedata\"\r\n}"]
```

so all I need is to construct this type of body from JSON and pass it as HTTPContent in C#.

From the provided example I could conclude that it's the array of strings. So I need to serialize my JSON, add it to the array and then convert it into HTTPContent. In case of "StringContent" how I should convert string array into string? This doesn't work:

```
string s = "[\"" + serialisedJson + "\"]";
HttpContent c = new StringContent(s, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

I'm getting JSON parsing error from the SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, all this time the answer was [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/blob/master/samples/rest-from-.net/Program.cs): CosmosDB API requires a specific Content-Type, which is apparently the case for stored procedures as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `StringContent`,something like this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey", "[\"PartitionKey\"]");
HttpContent content = new StringContent("[{\r\n\"id\" : \"someid\",\r\n\"data\": \"somedata\"\r\n}]", Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(baseUri, resourceLink),content);
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and got bad request response because SP can't parse the JSON it gets. This particular string causes "JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:2". Hence the question.